# Using classes in nodes

Tags: 7

I need a little bit of guidance, I made a custom class and im trying to use it in a node but of course it throwing a white screen at me. So my question is how can I go about using a custom class for d7 so I can include the tag in my node via php.

I put this code in the template.tpl.php file and tried using it in my node but it then gave the white screen.

```
<?php class Colors {

  public function red_form() {
        echo 'color red is here';
  }

    public function blue_form() {
        echo 'color blue is here';
  }

    public function green_form() {
        echo 'color green is here';
  }

    public function purple_form() {
        echo 'color purple is here';
  }

    public function yellow_form() {
        echo 'color yellow is here';
  }
}

$colorforms = new Colors();

?>
```

and im using this in the node.

```
Text here here and here.

<?php $colorforms->red_form(); ?>

More text here here and here.
```

the output im trying to get using the code above is.

```
Text here here and here.

color red is here

More text here here and here
```

is there a module or something for this? or anything to that nature, im a little in the dark on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix: declare the class in template.php but instantiate it in your node template (if you check your php error log you probably had something like "Call to a member function red_form() on a non-object in ..." in it).  Also, I am assuming it's a typo that you had $colorforms and $color_form in your example above.

Comment: yeah it was a typo on my end when posting here, however I did try what you suggested and it is still just the white screen but i dont see any errors

Comment: I'd look in your php error log then to see what is going on then...

Comment: its outputting a Undefined variable error, but if I try my code in static php file it works fine.

Comment: must be something drupal7ish then because I put your class code in my drupal6 template.php and then the `$colorforms=new Colors(); $colorforms->red_form();` in another template and it worked fine.

Comment: Could you try $colorforms->red_form(); in a node and see if it still works for you. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes.  I put the class Colors declaration in my template.php and `$colorforms=new Colors; $colorforms->red_form();` in my node.tpl.php file and it echoed out color red is here.

Comment: no no not the node.tpl file, a actual node from a content type, like if your making a post for example.

Comment: huh?  like inside a text field?  if so, you are looking for a filter.  Otherwise, you've lost me or I am having a really bad case of the Mondays.

Comment: lol its cool and yes I mean in the text field.

Comment: If that's what you are doing, I'd say make it easier on yourself and just declare functions, eg, `function my_module_or_theme_name_red_form()` and then the basic php filter will work just fine and dandy.  But running php in there is just sooooo risky that I'd really look into alternative means like writing a custom filter that allows only specific functions to be run.  For example, you could write one that changes [redform] into the output of red_form() pretty easily.  http://drupal.org/project/customfilter will do it if you don't want to write your own.

Comment: i think thats perfect for what im looking for, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Don't instantiate classes (or do any business logic) in your `.tpl.php` files: stuff in template files should be in its final, renderable form.

Instead, [use a preprocess function](http://drupal.org/node/223430) in `template.php`:

```
// Replace MYTHEME with your theme's short name
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['colorforms'] = new Color();
}
```

Then, in `node.tpl.php`, reference `$colorforms`<sup>1</sup>:

```
<?php $colorforms->red_form(); ?>
```

---

As an aside, consider breaking your class into a separate module: doing so would allow you to take advantage of Drupal's autoloader. [Create the custom module](http://drupal.org/node/361112), place the class in a separate file within the module's directory (let's say, `includes/color.php`).

In the custom module's `.info` file, add the following line:

```
files[] = includes/color.php
```

If you just want to take advantage of the autoloader and don't need any other custom functionality, just use a placeholder `.module` file:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * This file is a placeholder.
 */
```

---

<sup>Note 1</sup>: Also consider not `echo`ing out information in your class, but returning the string, to allow others to decide how to render the output:

```
public function red_form() {
  return 'color red is here';
}
```

and, assuming you used the solution mentioned here, use this in `node.tpl.php`:

```
<?php print $colorforms->red_form(); ?>
```

Comment: very true, but alas he wanted to put all of that in a text field and was really looking for a filter instead :)